# To what files does ` patch -p1` apply the patch in this example?

Tags: git, patch

For revert the changes to a file in a commit, from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2620822/156458

```
#!/bin/bash

function output_help {
    echo "usage: git-revert-single-file <sha1> <file>"
}

sha1=$1
file=$2

if [[ $sha1 ]]; then
git diff $sha1..$sha1^ -- $file | patch -p1
else
output_help
fi
```

To what files does `patch -p1` apply the patch file (i.e. the output of  `git diff $sha1..$sha1^ -- $file`)?

Does it apply to all the files in the working directory?

But the working directory might not be the same as the commit `$sha1`. So does it make sense to apply the difference between `$sha1^` and `$sha1` to the working directory, which might or might not be the same as `$sha1`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`git diff $sha1..$sha1^` produces a patch which reverts the `$sha1` commit (it lists the differences between that commit and its parent). If `$file` is specified, it limits that patch to the changes made to `$file` in the given commit.

That patch is then fed to `patch -p1`, which will strip the fake directory names used by `git` (`a/` and `b/`), and attempt to apply the patch to whichever files are listed in the patch (*i.e.*, `$file` if it was named and changed in the given commit, or all the files changed in the given commit, including files in sub-directories). If the files present in the current directory and its sub-directories are substantially different (or by extension, missing), `patch` will fail to apply the patch.

This is made possible by the fact that patches in unified format, as produced by `git diff` (and `diff -u`), include the names of the files being patched, and context for the patch. Here’s an example (not from `git`, but it shows the idea):

```
diff -ur cli-common-0.9+nmu1.orig/policy-remove cli-common-0.9+nmu1/policy-remove
--- cli-common-0.9+nmu1.orig/policy-remove  2015-02-25 21:34:08.000000000 +0100
+++ cli-common-0.9+nmu1/policy-remove   2017-04-08 20:47:09.029065259 +0200
@@ -11,4 +11,4 @@

 #echo "Removing GAC policy file ($POLICY) from available GACs"
 /usr/share/cli-common/gac-package-remove $POLICY > /dev/null
-rm /usr/share/cli-common/packages.d/$POLICY.installcligac
+rm -f /usr/share/cli-common/packages.d/$POLICY.installcligac
```

This patch says that it’s modifying the file named `cli-common-0.9+nmu1.orig/policy-remove` to produce the file named `cli-common-0.9+nmu1/policy-remove`. The change itself starts at line 11 and covers 4 lines, including context (that’s the `@@ -11,4`); in the target, the changed lines are in the same position (`+11,4 @@`). There are three lines of context above the change, then the change itself, deleting a line starting with `rm` and adding a line starting with `rm -f`. When `patch` applies this, it will look for the appropriately-named file (after removing path components if instructed to with a `-p` option), and compare the context in the file with the patch; only if the context matches (within a few lines, depending on the fuzz options) will the change be applied.

The whole point of this script is to try to revert the changes made to a single file in the given commit (hence its name). Whether that’s possible or not depends on the changes that have been made to the file since that commit; but it’s often quite useful in practice. (To revert a complete commit you’d use `git revert` instead.)

Comment: Thanks. (1) Do you mean that the stdout output of `git diff $sha1..$sha1^` contains both "the difference for changing `$sha1` to `$sha1^`" and "the files which `patch` can apply the difference to"?  (2) Are "the files which `patch` can apply the difference to" within  `$sha1`? (3) When running `patch -p1` with input from the output of `git diff`, does  `patch -p1` modify the commit `$sha1`, or does  `patch -p1` store the results in working directory without modifying the commit `$sha1`? (4) Does it make sense to modify or delete a commit? If yes, what commands can modify and delete a commit?

Comment: You’re asking me to write a book there... I’ve added an example of a patch in the hope of answering (1). I’m not sure what you mean by (2); `patch` can apply the patch to any file satisfying the constraints given in the patch (filename and change context). As for (3), you can’t modify a commit; the changes are applied to the current working directory without committing anything.

Comment: Regarding (4), again you can’t modify a commit in `git`, but you can replace commits (typically using `commit --amend`), and re-organise commits (with `git rebase`). The SHA-1 which identifies a commit is based on the commit’s contents, so you can’t ever modify *that* (short of introducing collisions of course). But replacing and re-organising commits is a common occurrence when developing with `git`, especially with tools such as Gerrit.